# FFMPEG: How to select X evenly spaced frames from a variable-length video including the first & last frame

Tags: ffmpeg, video, screenshot, selection

I need to extract a given number of evenly spaced screenshots from a "walkaround" video ensuring that the first and last frame are included.

I've tried using -r and select="mod" but the math always turns out a tiny bit off so that the last frame is either skipped or I get one a bit before the last (decimal rounding).

Any way to combine two "select frame at timestamp" tests with "select frame every x seconds" if I know the duration and framerate?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplistic python script for you...

```
#!/bin/env python3

import sys

def adjust(value):
  return int(int(value*10+0.5)/10)

if len(sys.argv)!=4:
  print('use:',sys.argv[0],' start stop steps',
        '\nPrints values evenly spread over the range from start to stop'
        )
  exit(1)

a, b, steps =sys.argv[1:]

a=float(a); b=float(b); steps=float(steps)
rnge=(b-a); stepval=(rnge/steps)

values=[ adjust(b) ]
value=a
while value < b:
  values.append( adjust(value) )
  value+=stepval

values=list(set(values))
values.sort()

i=1
for n in values:
  print(n,end=' ')
  i+=1
print()
```

...

Now install python and then do something similar to

> $ python3 evensteps.py 10 211 3

to get evenly spaced integers, which might be the frames to extract.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can come up with the frames/timestamps but it's the FFMPEG select statement that I can't figure out. It's got a sort of crazy syntax and I'm not sure how to translate a list of frames into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save - let's say - the first, the last, and every 51th frame of a 25 fps video, you should try:

```
$ ffmpeg -i <your-input> -ss 0.0 -vframes 1 -y first.png -vf fps=25/51 -y 51th_%02d.png -ss 60.0 -vframes 1 -y last.png
```

I tested it with a 1501-frame-long, 25 fps video, each frame containing its own timecode. The input video:

```
$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -i ff.mkv

Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'ff.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7989 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.54.100 ffv1
      DURATION        : 00:01:00.040000000
```

Thus, the very first frame should have the timecode of **00:00:00:00** and the very last should have **00:01:00:00**. However, the "-vf 25/51" filter starts frame extraction at the **25th** frame **00:00:01:00** of the video. The command above outputs a total of 31 files, with the following timecodes:

- first.png: **00:00:00:00** (very first frame, OK)
- 51th_01.png: **00:00:01:00** (should have started at zero)
- 51th_02.png: **00:00:03:01** (frame distance is OK)
- 51th_03.png: **00:00:05:02** (frame distance is OK)
- ...
- 51th_28.png: **00:00:56:02** (frame distance is OK)
- 51th_29.png: **00:00:58:03** (frame distance is OK)
- last.png: **00:01:00:00** (very last frame, OK)

Hope that helps.